# How to fix: index 122 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 122

Tags: index-error

I am new to coding and doing a project for my Uni. I keep on getting the following error:

index 122 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 122

I think the error is somewhere here:

```
def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):
data = []
labels = []
start_index = start_index + history_size
if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i)
    # Reshape data from (history_size,) to (history_size, 1)
    data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
    labels.append(dataset[i+target_size])
return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: In most languages, collection/list/array indexes start at 0 and end at length - 1. That means that if you have a length of 122 in axis 0, then the valid indexes are 0 to 121 (122 - 1). Using an index of 122 would be out of bounds, as it's 1 past the last index.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Can you point to a specific line? I am new to this so don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You can do it in the line where the loop starts: (`for i in range(start_index, end_index - 1)`, or in the code where `end_index` is assigned before the procedure is called. I can only see the out-of-context portion of your code that you've posted here.

Comment: What do you mean where end_index is assigned? I have posted the complete code? Am i missing anything?

Comment: Can you not read your own code? You're either assigning it when the procedure is called (when you pass `end_index` in as a parameter) or in the code you've posted (`if end_index is None:` and the line that follows it). Those are the two places where `end_index` could possibly be assigned, and you've posted one of them. The other possibility is the other location that you didn't post.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
for i in range(start_index, end_index + 1)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. Didn't work, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean `for i in range(start_index, end_index - 1)`?